# to Sending Email from an ASP classic Page with credentials

Tags: email, asp-classic, credentials

I need to send users credentials by email to the users of my app, that is build in asp
  classic, this is my issue, from a email account, sent information to an user, but 
  doesn´t send username and pass from that user, my code is this, how can manage the
  user/password? what the best way to do it? thanks in advance.

```
t1 = time()
estado=""
email="soporte.web@ipsos.com"       
mail_from = "Soporte <soporte.web@myenterprise.com>"
mail_destino = "Soporte Web Ipsos" & " <" & email &">"
mail_asunto = "Acceso BCI Satisfaccion " & user
ruta=request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")
on error resume next
mail_cc=""
Dim myMail
Set myMail = CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
myMail.MailFormat = 0   '0 (Mime format), 1 (default Plain Text format)'
myMail.BodyFormat = 0   '0 html, 1 texto'
myMail.Importance = 1   '0 Low, 1 Normal, 2 High '
myMail.From = mail_from
myMail.To = mail_destino
myMail.Cc = mail_cc
'myMail.Cco = mail_cco'
myMail.Subject = mail_asunto
myMail.Body = texto_email
'myMail.AttachFile ruta&"Carta2006.pdf"'
myMail.Send
Set myMail = Nothing
If err.num <> 0 Then   
Response.Write nombre & " / " & email & " / " & "CDONTS Error: " & err.num & " - " & 
err.description
estado="no"
End If
```

end sub

Comment: Do you mean that the email does not send? or that the email is sent but does not contain the user and password?

Comment: @NeilThompson the email sent but don´t contain de user and password, thanks for your fast replay, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - you need to edit your post to show how texto_email is constructed - as that is the email body that *should* contain the user and password. The code you have posted is essentially correct.

Comment: thanks @NeilThompson my problem is the sintaxis, I'm new in asp classic, and this code I get it from a tutorial in http://devguru.com/features/tutorials/cdonts/cdonts.asp so I don't know how "ask" for user/password, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic ASP there is no standard way (that I can remember) to deal with username/password, other than a using login page for authentication and session variables for maintaining state.

If you go to the code of the login page in your application and follow the logic you should see the login happen (where username and password are checked). You can then pop those values into a session variable (if this isn't done already) and pull them out later to send in the email.

As an aside, sending a user their username and password in a plain text email is generally discouraged as the email can be read in transit = an opportunity for hackers. But that's up to you...

Comment: Neil Thompson thanks for your reply, how can I pass that to my server? what is the best way to pass the "session varibles" to the server, thanks in advance.